# If every element of a ring is either potent or central, the ring is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring such that every element is potent ($x^k = x$, for some integer $k>1$) or central. Prove that $R$ is commutative.

My prove:

Let $x,y$ be elements of $R$, suppose one of them is central (x is central or y is central) then it is obviously that $xy=yx$ because of property of central.

But how to prove that is $x^m = x$, and $y^n = y$ for some integer $m>1$ and $n>1$ then $xy=yx$?

Comment: whats your attempt to solve it ?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! People will help you but will not do your work. So, please, show us what you tried and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: i've proved:                                                        let x,y is eement of R an one of them is central then xy=yx but i'm stuck in if both of them potent how to prove xy=yx>

Comment: Show your attempt in the question itself by editing it. It will be clearer.

Comment: Just a short note: If $x^m=m$ and $y^n=y$ in a ring, then one cannot conclude $xy=yx$ (think about group rings for example). The point is that *every* element is assumed to be potent or central; so one also has to use that $x+y$ is potent or central, etc. In case that every element is potent, the result is already quite hard and due to Jacobson (N. Jacobson, Structure of rings, A.M.S. Colloq. Publ. (1964)).